# How do I move pictures and videos from one iPad to another?

Tags: ipad

How do I transfer photos and videos between iPad and iPad 2?

Comment: Can you please add some more details? Are the iPads synced with the same iTunes installation, do you need to transfer directly or do you have a computer inbetween, are the iPads able to connect to the same WLAN?

Comment: ...will iPads be getting AirDrop one day?

Comment: @GEdgar Not likely. The way AirDrop works, it assumes an ability to do easy arbitrary file storage, and that's not available in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

This depends, do you have iCloud? as you can sync through iCloud.

You can also configure all the settings in iTunes. So you can import all the images into iTunes, once they are there you can connect the other iPad and sync them.

If you do not want to keep the iPad 1, you can just connect it to iTunes, sync it and then connect the iPad 2 and restore it from the back up of the 1st iPad.

Comment: Dropbox for iPad might also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The original question doesn't have enough detail to really offer a solution here. But to clarify previous answers, the fastest way to transfer photos and videos between an iPad and an iPad 2 would be to sync to a single installation of iTunes/iPhoto/Aperture.

A slower but simpler way would be to run Dropbox on the iPad, click on the UPLOAD tab at the bottom of the page, and upload all the photos and videos to the Dropbox. On the iPad 2, reverse the process and download all the photos back.

If you're only talking about a few photos and you don't want to do anything outside of the Photos app, you could simply email the photos to yourself from the iPad and save them to your photo library (via the Mail app) on the iPad 2.

I suspect all three answers sound simplistic, but it's hard to know what you're trying to achieve and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Use an iPad Transfer software such as [iPad-to-iPad](http://www.aiseesoft.com/ipad-transfer.html) to transfer videos, music, photos and file folders from iPad to iPad for backup or sharing with your friends.

This software comes in two versions, a Standard version for $29 USD and a Platinum version for $45 USD, unfortunately this software is Windows only.

Both versions have the following functionality:

> **Transfer files between iOS devices**
>
> This professional iPad Transfer allows users to transfer iPad files to other iPad device and even iPhone/iPod.

Comment: A transfer software touting Windows compatibility looks kind of strange to me. If you need a computer anyway why not just use iTunes?

Answer (score -1):

No additional computer or "Cloud" necessary!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ofUkg9Eb8s

works brilliantly if you have a Camera Connection Kit (non-Apple one may even do)

You may need to reset the target iPad (press Home & Power button) to get it to highlight "import".

Remember that your charging lead goes from the source iPad & CCK into the target iPad. This idea is great if you're on holiday in a camp site for example.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link to a video. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.