# Is AirDrop possible between iPad, iPhone and MacBook?

Tags: macos, iphone, ipad, airdrop, ios

A new MacBook came with something called AirDrop and worked between many MacBooks such as MacBook Pro and MacBook Air. Can I also use AirDrop to exchange data between Macs and iOS devices?

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is bad.

Comment: +1 to balance out unwarranted down vote without comment.

Comment: The key issue here are the two questions bundled into one: a) is AirDrop supported in iOS? b) what alternatives exist for wireless data exchange between OS X and iOS devices. As a) is answered below, I've edited the question accordingly. You may find stuff relating to b) on this site, otherwise please ask a new question.

Comment: We have two mods who disagree on this?! Ridiculous to make users to jump to-and-fro...

Comment: This is very disappointing. Not being able to use this great feature with an iphone or iPad seems counter-intutitive and goes against the ease-of-use and everything-just-works philosophy that made Apple what it is today. This is something that should just work—worse even; seems it was designed not to work to force us on to the cloud where we would have to send more money Apple's way.

Comment: Obligatory "this never would have happened if Steve Jobs were still alive."

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34234/

Comment: Looks like iOS 7 is going to have AirDrop

Comment: You can't Airdrop even between latest OSX 10.9 and iOS 7.0.4

Comment: http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/ says, "AirDrop is available on iPhone 5 or later, iPad (4th generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation) and requires an iCloud account."

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use AirDrop with iOS devices. It is a feature that is exclusive to supported Macs (and [unsupported Macs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/airdrop-on-unsupported-macs) through a hack, as you've pointed out).

If you are interested in sharing files with your iOS devices, I recommend a solution such as [SugarSync](http://www.sugarsync.com) or [DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com), or a Wi-Fi tool such as [Instashare](http://instashareapp.com).

Apple intends for you and developers to use [iCloud to get documents](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/documents.html) from PC to iOS, but it's not widespread yet and perhaps ever.

Comment: ...third-party services: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84323/airdrop-style-services-between-ios-devices-and-os-x-devices and my [edit](http://pastie.org/6389636).

Comment: According to http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/: "AirDrop is available on iPhone 5 or later, iPad (4th generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation) and requires an iCloud account."

Answer (score 8):

Looks like iOS 7 is going to have AirDrop as the new UI has an icon for AirDrop right next to the icon for AirPlay.

Answer (score 3):

It has been announced that [starting with OS X 10.10](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/06/os-x-yosemite-is-coming-and-it-will-redesign-the-entire-mac-desktop/), Airdrop will interoperate between OS X and iOS.

Comment: does this also require iOS 8, or will iOS 7 Airdrop work with Mac OS 10.10?

Answer (score 1):

Just update after IOS7 release.    Looks like the link between airdrop from supported IOS7 devices to supported OSX Mountain Lion is not working.   Probably something that should/will be completed with release Mavericks.

Comment: I think everyone hope so: Apple is shooting itself to leg if it turns away from Steve Jobs' insistence on compability/consistence/easy-usage. It is driving people crazy that they are naming things "airdrop" but different "airdrops" not compatible yet, hope soon! +1

Answer (score -1):

The best choice to share with macs, Windows, Linux, NAS servers, FTP, Dropbox, Google Drive,Time Capsule, etc is Quick Explorer.

I used instashare before and its similiar to airdrop but it works only with pictures (not bad, but not enough ) If you want to share andy file, mp3, wav, video, doc, pdf, and otherwise file formats Quick Explorer is the best choice. I've found that it's the best tool for this purpose as it handles different file types and platforms.

Comment: Are you referring to http://quixplorer.sourceforge.net ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! People visiting this site would like to know if you're in some way affiliated with the people behind the product.

Comment: I suspect the poster is referring to this: http://www.linkusnow.com/quickexplorer/index.php